# envfit function (vegan package) plotting entirely different arrows on identical columns from different datasheets

Tags: r, vegan

Hello: I'm struggling to plot five extrinsic (environmental) variables onto my NMDS plot. Envfit (vegan package in R) yields different results when I run it on individual columns versus when I run it on the entire datasheet. When I run it individually the arrows look "right", but when I run it on the entire datasheet it looks very "wrong".

My NMDS plot contains moss data grouped into four communities by the (permafrost 2015=light blue, no permafrost 2015=light orange, permafrost 2021= dark blue, no permafrost 2021= dark orange)

[image]

Previously, I had an two old datasheets with dozen of columns of environmental data (combo.env.15.21 and veg.TOT2.15.21). I only needed 7 columns for my project (organic soil depth, moisture class, latitude, elevation). The 5th and 6th (year, permafrost presence) operated as a "check" to see whether my arrows were plotting correctly, since in theory, year should be horizontal and permafrost presence should be vertical in order to drive my community groupings.

Since I only needed 7 columns out of my datasheets, I ran my envfits separately. Here is my code and an image of how they plot. You can see they pass the "check", with year driving horizontal divergence and permafrost driving vertical divergence.

```
elevationNMDS<-envfit(live.moss.mds~Elev_start, data=combo.env.15.21, perm=999, choices=c(1,2), display="sites", na.rm=TRUE, arrow.mul = 1, add = TRUE)
plot(elevationNMDS, col = "green", cex = 1.0, label = "elevation")

latitudeNMDS<-envfit(live.moss.mds~Lat_start, data=combo.env.15.21, perm=999, choices=c(1,2), display="sites", na.rm=TRUE, arrow.mul = 1, add = TRUE)
plot(latitudeNMDS, col = "magenta", cex = 1.0, label = "latitude")

orgNMDS<-envfit(live.moss.mds~avg_organic_depth, data=veg.TOT2.15.21, perm=999, choices=c(1,2), display = "sites", na.rm = TRUE, arrow.mul = 1, add = TRUE)
plot(orgNMDS, col="saddlebrown", lwd=10, cex = 1.0, labels = "organic")

moistNMDS<-envfit(live.moss.mds~moisture_class_num, data=veg.TOT2.15.21, perm=999, choices=c(1,2), display = "sites", na.rm = TRUE, arrow.mul = 1, add = TRUE)
plot(moistNMDS, col="purple",cex = 1.0, labels = "moisture")

actNMDS<-envfit(live.moss.mds~active_layer_depth, data=veg.TOT2.15.21, perm=999, choices=c(1,2), display = "sites", na.rm = TRUE, arrow.mul = 1, add = TRUE)
plot(actNMDS, col="turquoise",cex = 1.5, labels = " ")

permNMDS<-envfit(live.moss.mds~permafrost_num, data=combo.env.15.21, perm=0, choices=c(1,2), display = "sites", na.rm = TRUE)
plot(permNMDS, col="royalblue",cex = 1.5, labels = "permafrost")

yearNMDS<-envfit(live.moss.mds~year, data=combo.env.15.21, perm=0, choices=c(1,2), display = "sites", na.rm = TRUE)
plot(yearNMDS, col="black",cex = 1.5, labels = "year")
```

[image]

Recently, I've been seeing everyone on the internet runs envfit on ALL their environmental variables together by simply running the whole datasheet. Since I originally had two datasheets, I combined them using their unique id field, and then created a unique dataset with only the 7 variables I needed. Like this:

```
envdataTEST <- merge(combo.env.15.21,veg.TOT2.15.21,by.x ="X", by.y = "unique_id")
rownames(envdataTEST)<-combo.env.15.21[,2]
envdataTEST<-envdataTEST[c(3,5,11,56,58,116,123)]
```

Result:

[image]

I then ran envfit on the entire dataframe as I've seen everyone else doing it:

```
allenvNMDS <- envfit(live.moss.mds, envdataTEST, perm=999, choices=c(1,2), display = "sites", na.rm = TRUE)
plot(allenvNMDS, col = "red")
```

As you can see, this gives me entirely different envfit results, that do NOT pass my "check" since the permafrost and year arrows are not pointing where they should:

[image]

My question is this: is vegan doing different things when running envfit on an individual column versus the entire dataset? If running them individually is giving me results that "make more sense" with my data, is it ok to do that?

Comment: One thing it does differently is handling missing values. It uses listwise deletion meaning that the whole row (observation) is ignored if *any* variable has missing value. You can use R command complete.cases() to see which observations are retained (and how many are retained).

Comment: Ok this makes sense, thank you @JariOksanen! So even if I'm performing my envfit on an individual column (live.moss.mds~avg_organic_depth, data=veg.TOT2.15.21...), it will delete rows that have missing data in other unused columns?

Comment: not so: *unused* variables will not considered, but all variables on the right-hand-side of the formula will be considered. Any NA in these variables means that the whole row is ignored. Naturally, I don't know your data and its pattern of missing values, but this is a thing where envfit works differently in one-variable and multi-variable models.

Comment: In your opinion @JariOksanen, would it be feasible to run all my envfits separately, since I am running into this issue with NAs? I wasn't sure if there's some statistical reason in addition to convenience alone why people on the internet seem to run envfit on the entire datasheet