# Vegan's envfit results changing when performed on a single column depending on neighboring columns

Tags: r, vegan

I have already asked this question previously ([envfit function (vegan package) plotting entirely different arrows on identical columns from different datasheets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76640946/22192598)) and got some great responses concerning the way envfit deals with NAs (whole row deletion), however, unfortunately it didn't resolve my issue.

Essentially, I have two duplicate datasheets with the same columns. The second one was created because I realized one column contained data that was wrong, so I manually corrected it and in doing so, eliminated a lot of NAs by replacing them with numbers.

I've been running envfit individually on separate columns, therefore I don't see why results would be different between these datasheets. The column I fixed, `active_layer_depth`, makes sense for why it would plot differently. But the other columns are all "off", and don't make sense for the data I have.

Here is my code to create the two datasheets, the first one before I realized "`active_layer_depth`" contained some false values and the second one where I corrected that column. As you can see, I ran all the envfits separately so as not to run into the NA casewise deletion issue. In both plots, "`permafrost_num`" should point straight up (since my permafrost site groupings are in blue) and "`year`" should point straight to the right (since 2015 groups are on the left and 2021 groups on the right). In my supposedly "corrected" datasheet, this is not the case.

> ###MAKING FINAL DATASHEET FOR ENVFIT
>
> #First dataset:
>
> combo.env.15.21.2<-read.csv("combo.env.15.21.2.csv")
> combo.env.15.21.2<-(dplyr::full_join(combo.env.15.21.2,veg.TOT2, by = "unique_id"))
> combo.env.15.21.2<-(dplyr::select(combo.env.15.21.2, unique_id,
> year.x, permafrost.x, permafrost_num, avg_organic_depth.x, Lat_start, Elev_start, active_layer_depth, moisture_class_num.y))
> rownames(combo.env.15.21.2)<-combo.env.15.21.2[,1] #changing rownames to be unique ids
> combo.env.15.21.2<-(dplyr::select(combo.env.15.21.2, -c(unique_id)))
> complete.cases(combo.env.15.21.2) #lots of NAs resulting from active layer column
>
> #plotting first dataset:
>
> elevationNMDS<-envfit(live.moss.mds~Elev_start, data=combo.env.15.21.2, perm=999, choices=c(1,2), display="sites", na.rm=TRUE)
> plot(elevationNMDS, col = "green", cex = 1.0, label = "elevation")
>
> latitudeNMDS<-envfit(live.moss.mds~Lat_start, data=combo.env.15.21.2, perm=999, choices=c(1,2), display="sites", na.rm=TRUE)
> plot(latitudeNMDS, col = "magenta", cex = 1.0, label = "latitude")
>
> orgNMDS<-envfit(live.moss.mds~avg_organic_depth.x, data=combo.env.15.21.2, perm=999, choices=c(1,2), display = "sites", na.rm = TRUE)
> plot(orgNMDS, col="saddlebrown", lwd=10, cex = 1.0, labels = "organic")
>
> moistNMDS<-envfit(live.moss.mds~moisture_class_num.y, data=combo.env.15.21.2, perm=999, choices=c(1,2), display = "sites", na.rm = TRUE)
> plot(moistNMDS, col="purple",cex = 1.0, labels = "moisture")
>
> actNMDS<-envfit(live.moss.mds~active_layer_depth, data=combo.env.15.21.2, perm=999, choices=c(1,2), display = "sites", na.rm = TRUE)
> plot(actNMDS, col="turquoise",cex = 1.0, labels = "active layer")
>
> permNMDS<-envfit(live.moss.mds~permafrost_num, data=combo.env.15.21.2, perm=0, choices=c(1,2), display = "sites", na.rm = TRUE)
> plot(permNMDS, col="royalblue",cex = 1.0,)
>
> yearNMDS<-envfit(live.moss.mds~year.x, data=combo.env.15.21.2, perm=999, choices=c(1,2), display = "sites", na.rm = TRUE)
> plot(yearNMDS, col="black",cex = 1.0, labels = "year")
>
> #now to fix active layer data
>
> envfit.data<-combo.env.15.21.2 #making a copy of the datasheet above
> write.csv(envfit.data, "envfit.data.csv")
> envfit.data<-read.csv("envfit.data.csv") #fixed the active layer depth values, cleared up a bunch of NAs
> rownames(envfit.data)<-envfit.data[,1]   #fix rownames
> envfit.data<-(dplyr::select(envfit.data, -c(X))) #delete duplicate rowname field
> complete.cases(envfit.data) #only a few NAs remain
>
> #plotting second datasheet with fixed active layer depth column:
>
> elevationNMDS<-envfit(live.moss.mds~Elev_start, data=envfit.data, perm=999, choices=c(1,2), display="sites", na.rm=TRUE)
> plot(elevationNMDS, col = "green", cex = 1.0, label = "elevation")
>
> latitudeNMDS<-envfit(live.moss.mds~Lat_start, data=envfit.data, perm=999, choices=c(1,2), display="sites", na.rm=TRUE)
> plot(latitudeNMDS, col = "magenta", cex = 1.0, label = "latitude")
>
> orgNMDS<-envfit(live.moss.mds~avg_organic_depth, data=envfit.data, perm=999, choices=c(1,2), display = "sites", na.rm = TRUE)
> plot(orgNMDS, col="saddlebrown", lwd=10, cex = 1.0, labels = "organic")
>
> moistNMDS<-envfit(live.moss.mds~moisture_class_num, data=envfit.data, perm=999, choices=c(1,2), display = "sites", na.rm = TRUE)
> plot(moistNMDS, col="purple",cex = 1.0, labels = "moisture")
>
> actNMDS<-envfit(live.moss.mds~active_layer_depth, data=envfit.data, perm=999, choices=c(1,2), display = "sites", na.rm = TRUE)
> plot(actNMDS, col="turquoise",cex = 1.0, labels = "active layer")
>
> permNMDS<-envfit(live.moss.mds~permafrost_num, data=envfit.data, perm=999, choices=c(1,2), display = "sites", na.rm = TRUE)
> plot(permNMDS, col="royalblue",cex = 1.0,)
>
> yearNMDS<-envfit(live.moss.mds~year, data=envfit.data, perm=999, choices=c(1,2), display = "sites", na.rm = TRUE)
> plot(yearNMDS, col="black",cex = 1.0, labels = "year")

Here is the result of the first datasheet. As you can see, `year` and `permafrost_num` point where they are supposed to:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i05OH.png)

Here is the result of my second datasheet, where I fixed the `active_layer_depth` column. Here, for whatever reason, `permafrost_num` and `year` are pointing in directions that don't make sense with my ellipses groupings.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5R0m.png)

QUESTIONS: why am I running into different results even when running envfit on individual columns, which are essentially copy/pasted from the first datasheet? Is there any reason that clearing up some NAs in my `active_layer_depth` column would cause the "`year`" and "`permafrost_num`" arrows to suddenly plot differently from what my ellipses/community groupings are telling me? (which is: timepoints on horizontal axis, permafrost presence on vertical axis)

Comment: Please make a reproducible example. I tried to reproduce your problem but in vain: results did not change. Just the same arrows alone or in any combination. The only thing that I know to influence the results are the missing values. Missing values in a single variable will be ignored (with `na.rm=TRUE`), but if you have several variables, all rows with any missing value will be ignored, and this can change the data drastically. Have you inspected this issue? What did you find? Which observations had missing values? Could their pattern be influential?

Comment: In my comment I was asking about *pattern* of missing values. Your ordination graphs have most points closely packed, but then a couple of points far away from others, in particular in the darkblue ellipse. These deviant points influence directions of arrows strongly, and if they have missing data, the direction of the arrows will change.